# s#arp repository constructor injection for wcf service/client

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, s#arp-architecture, s#arp

I understand there is a s#arp contrib collection of dlls but not much documentation (as far as I can see). I intend to use the s#arp architecture in a wcf service (console app hosted). Could someone please provide some code that shows me how to (constructor) inject a repository into a wcf service/client? Is there a transaction attribute for wcf methods similar to that for controller actions in asp.net mvc? Thanks.

PS:

The northwind example:

[northwind](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Northwind)

supposedly contains an example but the downloaded vs solution does not load properly.

Comment: Instead of having many WCF service classes that all have dependencies and need injecting, I'm much more a fan of having a WCF service that just has a single service with a single method. This way you don't need injecting into your services and your WCF service becomes maintenance free. Take a look [here](http://bit.ly/RrJRvD).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used WCF in a while, but follow the steps here:

https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture-Contrib/wiki/preparing-your-application-to-use-attributes-with-Castle-facilities

You need to add the initialisation code at the start of the app.

Instead of downloading the dlls, just add them using nuget. from the nuget package manager console:

```
install-package SharpArchContrib.Core
install-package SharpArchContrib.Domain
install-package SharpArchContrib.Castle
```

There is some documentation about the transaction attribute here, which should provide a starting point WCF:

https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture-Contrib/wiki/Transaction-attribute-%28supports-nhibernate-or-system.transaction.-works-with-asp.net%2C-wcf%2C-windows-gui-and-windows-service-applications%29

Chris Richards has posted an example on how to use SharpArch in WCF Console App
https://github.com/yellowfeather/TestWcfService

Comment: Thanks. Will check this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks all this helps but not for a console app hosted wcf service. At least for me ...